# Line by line text editing with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Dear stackoverflow community,

I am having troubling in a text-editing job using bash. Here is what I want to do: with a input file like this:

```
A B 0
C D 1
E F 2
C D 2
```

I want to append another column based on the information of the first 3 columns, this will be a line-by-line task with conditional judgement.

Specifically, for a given line, if it was 0 in the third column, the appended value will be two copies of value in the first column, if it was 1 in the third column, the appended value will be one copy of the first column and one copy of the second column, if it was 2 in the third column, I will have two copies of value in the second column. At the end of the day, I would want to have this:

```
A B 0 AA
C D 1 CD
E F 2 FF
C D 2 DD
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Xulong

Comment: Just translate your description directly into an `if` statement in `awk`. What's the problem? Please show what you've tried, and we'll help you understand where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '$3==0{$4=$1$1} $3==1{$4=$1$2} $3==2{$4=$2$2} 1' file
A B 0 AA
C D 1 CD
E F 2 FF
C D 2 DD
```

Comment: No, it's the right answer, can't imagine why it got downvoted. +1

Comment: Thanks so much Ed, I guess someone didn't interpret question (or answer) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed (for educational use only, awk is probably the best way):

```
sed 's/\(.\) \(.\) 0/\1 \2 0 \1\1/;s/\(.\) \(.\) 1/\1 \2 1 \1\2/;s/\(.\) \(.\) 2/\1 \2 2 \2\2/'
```

Comment: If the line contains more than 3 columns this may result in false matches because the substitute command has not been anchored to the start of the line also it presupposes that the first and second columns are a single character long.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)\s+0/s//&\2\1\1/;/^(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)\s+1/s//&\2\1\3/;//^(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)\s+2/s//&\2\3\3/' file
```

This appends a fourth column (or inserts if the line has more than three columns) depending on the third column.